# Substituir id por nome em tabela

Tags: php

Então galera, eu tenho  essa tabela com informações como: id, aluno, computador, data de registro, hora de entrada, hora de saida e motivo, mas em aluno e computador eu quero mostrar o nome/ descrição e não o id. Segue aí meu código.

Aluno e computador são de outra tabela

```
public function buscaTodos() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->tabela;
    $sqle = $this->con->query($sql);

    $dados = $sqle->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $dados;
}
$registro = new Registro();
$dados = $registro->buscaTodos();


<table class='table][1]][1] table-bordered table-striped'>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Aluno</th>
            <th>Computador</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Hora de Entrada</th>
            <th>Hora de Saída</th>
            <th>Motivo</th>
            <th>Opções</th>
        </tr>

    <?php

    foreach($dados as $r){

        $id=$r['id'];
        $aluno=$r['id_aluno'];
        $computador=$r['id_computador'];
        $dt_registro = $r['dt_registro'];
        $hr_entrada = $r['hr_entrada'];
        $hr_saida = $r['hr_saida'];
        $motivo = $r['motivo'];



    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$id?></td>
            <td><?=$aluno?></td>
            <td><?=$computador?></td>
            <td><?=$dt_registro?></td>
            <td><?=$hr_entrada?></td>
            <td><?=$hr_saida?></td>
            <td><?=$motivo?></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

[image: aparece assim]

Comment: Qual é a pergunta?

Comment: jovem, se os campos Nome e descrição estão na mesma tabela, basta trocar no $r['id_aluno'] por $r['nome_aluno'] por exemplo, o código está bem simples mas precisa saber da estrutura da tabela

Comment: estão em outra tabela

Comment: Não me parece que os campos  `aluno` e `computador` estão populados nessa tabela. Se estiverem em outra, você precisará fazem um `join`, talvez utilizando o próprio `id` de `aluno`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, bom, você quer fazer uma pesquisa um pouco complexa no seu banco de dados, usando o id do aluno e do computador para se referir as suas respectivas tabelas, pegando o nome deles.

Para isso você deve fazer uma query um pouco complexa também, utilizando join. e on. Eu não sei como seu banco de Dados está modelado, mas tenho uma query parecida com oque você quer, que pode te servir de base para criar a sua. segue o código:

```
function buscaProjetoPorUsuario($id_usuario){
        $select = $this->conexao->prepare("SELECT p.id, p.nome, p.descricao, p.dono, p.id_usuario,p.data, p.porc_marketing, p.porc_site, p.porc_desing, u.nome FROM projetos P join usuarios U on (P.id_usuario = U.id) WHERE U.id = '$id_usuario'");
        $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $select->execute();
        $projetos = $select->fetchAll();
        return $projetos;
    }
```

Agora irei explicar a query pra você, trecho por trecho.

O objetivo dessa query é buscar as informações de um projeto, e buscar o nome de um usuario usando o id_usuario, para se referenciar a tabela usuarios.

primeiro eu defino tudo oque eu quero buscar usando:

`SELECT p.id, p.nome, p.descricao...` e `u.nome`

depois dou um `FROM projetos P, usuarios U on (P.id_usuario = U.id)`

Aqui estou defenindo que quando uso a letra P, em `p.id, p.descricao...` estou se referindo a tabela Projetos, e quando uso a letra U estou se referindo a tabela Usuarios, depois digo `on (P.id_usuario = U.id)`, isso faz com que a query se relacione com a tabela Usuarios, usando o campo id_usuario, para se relacionar com o campo id da tabela Usuario.

Espero que tenha entendido, caso precise de ajuda, compartilhe a estrutura das suas tabelas no banco de dados, para podermos te ajudar a montar uma query.